# Linq To SharePoint entities not counting all items in a document library

Tags: list, sharepoint-server, development, splistitem, linq

I want to count then number of documents in a sharepoint document library in which contains about 100 thousand items. Using the code below, the exact number of documents are returned:

```
SPList oList = oWebsite.Lists["RSAsLibrary"];
for (int i = 0; i < oList.ItemCount; i++)
{
    count += 1;
}
```

but then doing a Linq to sharepoint entity query returns about 91,000 documents that's about 10,000 documents less:

```
List<RSAsLibraryBenefitsCT> RSASchedules = scanningsiteDB.GetList<RSAsLibraryBenefitsCT>("RSAsLibrary").Where(x => x.DocReferenceNo != null).ToList();
var RsaScheldulesDocs = from doc in RSASchedules 
                            select (doc.Name);
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to count the list that way `ItemCount`.

```
count = oList.ItemCount;
```

`ItemCount` includes folders and files inside them. Try removing the where clause and see if the number aligns.

Comment: I tried removing the where clause, yet it did not work

Comment: Is the folder structure in your list flat? Wondering if it's conceivable the folders are not being loaded in the CSOM query. What count does the list settings page give you?

Comment: It gives the count oList.ItemCount gives and there are no folder in the library, just documents

Comment: Aight, just throwing out thoughts here. Do all documents have Name field?

Comment: Yes they do, Infact I checked if they were all checked in and yes they were checked in

Comment: Interesting, I wonder if there is some kind of throttling being done in the background. Will throw another answer for a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using SPListItems.

```
SPListItemCollection items = oList.GetItems("Name");
SPListItem item = null;
List<string> docNames = new List<string>();
foreach (SPListItem item in items)
{
    docNames.Add(item.Name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Thor. Is there a way to find the date an item was created using this method. Thanks

Comment: `DateTime created = (DateTime)item["Created_x0020_Date"];`

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/michael_yeager/2008/11/03/reference-list-for-sharepoint-internal-field-names/ helpful reference list for internal names.

Comment: If this solution solves your problem please mark it as accepted so that it can be used as reference for other searches.

Comment: Please where do I place the datetime created code. I placed it my linq to sharepoint entity file and it says item cannot be found

Comment: I don't understand the question. Sounds like you are in a different problem now. You are welcome to create a new question with where you are stuck and link to it here.

Comment: What I am asking is do I put this code DateTime created = (DateTime)item["Created_x0020_Date"]; in my sp metal generated file

Comment: The `item` here is your entity object. We are accessing the field of that object. I don't recommend assigning to that field because that field is an internally generated Sharepoint field. But now you have the DateTime object indicating when this item was created in the variable called `created`. Gone too far off-topic here though.